# why sometime i get the cursor null or count equal to zero

Tags: uri, android-arrayadapter, android-contentprovider, android-spinner, android-cursor

My apliction works fine ,it updates my spinner but sometime when I start my activity cursor becomes null and spinner list will be blank ,why?.It seems like my cursor is null or its count is zero. Though  it works fine most of the time so there is no chance of cursor being null or emplty.**very strange behavior**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String[] data = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
    ArrayList<String> path;
    Spinner path_spinner;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.MainActivity);
    path= new ArrayList<String>();
    path_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.folder_spinner);
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,data, null, null, null);
    if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0)
     {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            path.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA))
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> path_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, path);
    path_spinner.setAdapter(path_adapter);
    }
    }
```

**Update**

if any uri is accessd at this time it gives 
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);

```
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,"audio" + audiofile.getName());

values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
Uri base = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Uri newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);
```

07-24 15:52:22.300: E/AndroidRuntime(2583): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown URI: content://media/external/audio/media

it was all working fine before the cursor problem .It seems like content provider is not accesible at the moment. **why?**

Comment: cursor might be `null`, when there are no touches on screen...

Comment: @Opsenas cursor can't be null bcoz it works fine most of the time

Comment: What is the difference between cursor_fol and cursor?

Comment: Got it. After the edit there is no difference.

Comment: @Y2isorry actually by mistake i wrote  cursor_fol it is cursor only .i updated the question

Comment: May be sometimes external storage volume is not ready?

Comment: @Y2i may be, but what is the solution for that

Comment: check the availability lol

Comment: @Mohit ji y to check availabilty if it works all the time except some random time

Comment: coz exception occurs what if i remove sdcard lol

Comment: you will have to think each and every condition